# How to get "Inbox by Google"-reminders via a Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-inbox

Is it possible to get all Inbox by Google reminders via Google App Script?

I can't find any reference for accessing Google Inbox stuff. Mail data is covered with Gmail API, but no information about new Inbox by Google features, like the reminders.

I would like to make a printable sheet from all undone reminders/tasks.